# What is the proper way to calculate knot vector for the Cox De Boor algorithm?

Tags: ios, bezier, curve

I am currently trying to implement the Cox De Boor algorithm for drawing bezier curves. I've managed to produce something acceptable with a set degree, number of control points and a predefined knot vector, but I want to adapt my code so that it will function given any number of control points and any degree. I'm 90% certain that the problems I am currently encountering, i.e. that the path goes wandering off to point 0/0, are due to me not properly calculating knot vectors. If anyone can give me a hint or two I'd be grateful. Note that I am presently calculating each dimension (in this case just x and y) individually; I will eventually adapt this code to use the same precalculations for all dimensions. I may also adjust it to use C arrays rather than NSArrays, but from what I've seen there's no real speed advantage to doing so.

I am currently producing a degree 3 curve using 5 control points with a knot vector of {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}.

```
- (double) coxDeBoorForDegree:(NSUInteger)degree span:(NSUInteger)span travel:(double)travel knotVector:(NSArray *)vector
{
    double k1 = [[vector objectAtIndex:span] doubleValue];
    double k2 = [[vector objectAtIndex:span+1] doubleValue];
    if (degree == 1) {
        if (k1 <= travel && travel <= k2) return 1.0;
        return 0.0;
    }

    double k3 = [[vector objectAtIndex:span+degree-1] doubleValue];
    double k4 = [[vector objectAtIndex:span+degree] doubleValue];
    double density1 = k3 - k1;
    double density2 = k4 - k2;
    double equation1 = 0.0, equation2 = 0.0;

    if (density1 > 0.0) equation1 = ((travel-k1) / density1) * [self coxDeBoorForDegree:degree-1 span:span travel:travel knotVector:vector];
    if (density2 > 0.0) equation2 = ((k4-travel) / density2) * [self coxDeBoorForDegree:degree-1 span:span+1 travel:travel knotVector:vector];

    return equation1 + equation2;
}



- (double) valueAtTravel:(double)travel degree:(NSUInteger)degree points:(NSArray *)points knotVector:(NSArray *)vector
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < points.count; i++) {
        float weight = [self coxDeBoorForDegree:degree+1 span:i travel:travel knotVector:vector];
        if (weight > 0.001) total += weight * [[points objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found this very useful webpage:
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/PARA-knot-generation.html

Hence anyone with the same problem can use the following method to generate a suitable knot vector, where 'controls' is the number of control points affecting the line segment, and 'degree' is... well, the degree of the curve! Don't forget that degree cannot equal or exceed the number of control points in the curve:

```
- (NSArray *) nodeVectorForControlCount:(NSUInteger)controls degree:(NSUInteger)degree
{    
    NSUInteger knotIncrement = 0;
    NSUInteger knotsRequired = controls + degree + 1;
    NSMutableArray *constructor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:knotsRequired];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < knotsRequired; i++) {
        [constructor addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)knotIncrement]];
        if (i >= degree && i < controls) knotIncrement++;
    }

    NSArray * returnArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:constructor];
    [constructor release];
    return returnArray;    
}
```